# On click URL is adding %7B%7Bsecure_base_url%7D%7D

Tags: magento, magento2

In my magento url after run setup:upgrade command. All of sudden in every url at frontend have `%7B%7Bsecure_base_url%7D%7D` in their url. It means url is not converting `{{secure_base_url}}` properly. Anyone have idea why it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you face this issue then the solution is in the db. You should check whether your table `core_config_data` have entry against path `web/secure/base_link_url` or not. If not then add entry for `web/secure/base_link_url` and in value add your secure base url.